# Slow FileGDB Performance in GDAL

Tags: gdal, ogr, c++, file-geodatabase, performance

I am attempting to write many ASPRS LAS point files into an ESRI File Geodatabase using my compilation of GDAL 1.9.2. The FileGDB driver for GDAL/OGR appears to be incredibly slow when writing large files, taking as much as 45 minutes to write just 8 million point records. Write speeds of FileGDB using GDAL on a SATA3 drive are somewhere on the order of 200 kilobytes per second, which is unacceptably slow when I'm trying to convert terrabytes of data.

I noticed in the FileGDB documentation that defining the FGDB_BULK_LOAD macro should improve performance for large datasets, but I noticed no change in performance when I wrote a line into the "nmake.opt" file with the text "FGDB_BULK_LOAD = YES" immediately after the FGDB_LIB line.

Admittedly, a FileGDB is not the ideal way to store billions of point data records, but that's a gripe for another time. Have I correctly used the FGDB_BULK_LOAD feature? Is that supposed to be in *my* source code, not the GDAL build?

Thanks.

**UPDATE: Proper Usage:** (Answered in chat)

The `FGDB_BULK_LOAD` setting is properly stored as an environment variable for the GDAL/OGR process. This is set on the command line during the ogr exe call as shown by Ragi. Using the GDAL functions, it can be set programmatically **for the entire process** with

```
 CPLSetConfigOption("FGDB_BULK_LOAD", "YES");
```

or just **for the current thread** using

```
 CPLSetThreadLocalConfigOption("FGDB_BULK_LOAD", "YES");
```

`FGDB_BULK_LOAD` must be set prior to calling `FGdbDataSource::CreateLayer()`. It was unclear whether `OGRCleanupAll()` unset this variable, but it is safe to call multiple times to be sure.

Using that option boosted performance to be around 5.5x faster for writing millions to tens of millions of points.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

FGDB_BULK_LOAD is not a compilation setting, it is a configuration option for the command line tools (can also be done programmatically).

```
ogr2ogr --config FGDB_BULK_LOAD YES -f "FileGDB" MyFileGDB.gdb myKML.kml
```

Would create a filegdb and load the KML vector data to it. Let me know if your performance still sucks. By the way, what platform are you on?

**Update:**

Just to summarize what was discussed in chat and IRC:

For programmatic access:

```
 OGRDataSource* datasource = driver->Open("c:/myfilegdb.gdb", TRUE); 
 char* options[] = { "FGDB_BULK_LOAD=YES" , NULL }; 
 OGRLayer newlayer = datasource->CreateLayer("tiny", NULL, wkbPoint25D, options);
```

should be the equivalent.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm on Windows 7x64, coding in C++ on Qt Creator and compiling with MSVC2010. I didn't realize that was a command line option. Is it possible to tap into that performance improvement when coding from the library?

Comment: General GDAL/OGR gripe: most of the configuration and usage instructions on the driver pages are targetted solely toward commandline usage, whereas my use case requires integration of the GDAL/OGR library into my code. Is there a developer-targetted doc resource that I don't know about?

Comment: @Phlucious There is the Resources section here: http://www.gdal.org/ogr/ that has plenty of developer documentation. At the end, the best documentation is the source code itself. The entire source code for the FileGDB driver is only 7 files, and it is available here https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/tree/trunk/gdal/ogr/ogrsf_frmts/filegdb . In fact, if you want to see how how the flag gets used, you can look here: https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/trunk/gdal/ogr/ogrsf_frmts/filegdb/FGdbLayer.cpp#L351

Comment: The way the setting gets passed around is simply an array of strings. You can find that out by looking here It gets passed as an array of strings https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/trunk/gdal/ogr/ogrsf_frmts/filegdb/FGdbDriver.cpp#L122

Comment: I have browsed through the source code for the FileGDB driver but don't understand your comment. How is the FGdbDriver::CreateDataSource option getting passed when Line 130 explicitly states that options are ignored?https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/trunk/gdal/ogr/ogrsf_frmts/filegdb/FGdbDriver.cpp#L130

Comment: @Phlucious Good question. There are **datasource** creation options and there are **layer** creation options. In this case, the *datasource* represents the *FileGDB Workspace*, and the *layer* represents the *FileGDB Table/FeatureClass*. Tables are put in load mode (i.e "stop index updating"), not Workspaces. Hence, what you see.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6381/discussion-between-phlucious-and-ragi-yaser-burhum)

Comment: For clarity, although your syntax in the edited text is correct, the FGDB_BULK_LOAD option is *not* a setting for layer creation _or_ datasource creation, but instead it is stored as an environment variable that is queried by the FileGDB driver. It should therefore be set using one of the many methods for editing the environment, such as in the examples in my edit.

Comment: @Phlucious Mmmm. Looking at the code, you are right. IMHO it is better if it is a layer creation option since it would be give you control over which table does it. But perhaps this is a good time for adding some stuff for "bulk mode" for the entire GDAL/OGR API as opposed to being FileGDB-specific (for example, PostGIS could benefit from this, too). I'll discuss in chat to see if there is an interest for that. As far as the performance itself, did it make a considerable difference for you?

Comment: What you say makes sense. In my application, with feature classes on the order of millions to tens of millions of points, I saw a performance boost of 5.5 to 6.0 times. Pretty impressive! I also learned that you can have multiple threads writing to the same FileGDB as long as they write to different items, which boosts performance even more.